# Confusing behavior from UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, behavior

I'm trying to set up a popover to appear that displays a UIDatePicker when I press a button, however I'm getting some very confusing behavior. I created a view controller that housed nothing but the UIDatePicker, wired one up in the class i needed it in, and added it to a new UIPopoverController like this:

```
self.timePickerPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.timePickerViewController];
```

then I present it like so:

```
[timePickerPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:prepTimeButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

(prepTimeButton being the button that was pressed). However, I just get the following result:

[image: Broken UIPopoverController]

Instead of it displaying next to the button that was pressed and at the target size (it's way too tall right now; should only be the size of the date picker). I also tried giving it a custom view of the proper location and size in which to display, but that didn't help much (just shifted the popover to the right half of the screen). What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Is `self.view` the direct superview of `prepTimeButton`? Perhaps `prepTimeButton` is nested in a subview, in that case you'd need to use that as the `inView:` parameter (or convert the coordinates).

Did you set the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property of your view controller?

Comment: `prepTimeButton` is indeed a direct subview of `self.view`. Setting `contentSizeForViewInPopover` fixed the size issue, but it's still presenting in the upper left of the screen (even if I try to present in the previously mentioned custom view in the appropriate location).

Comment: What's the parent class of that button? For a TableView or a ScrollView you need additional offset calculation for the button's rect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set both `contentSizeForViewInPopover` on the internal view controller and `popoverContentSize` on the `UIPopoverController` itself.